# Is it a bad idea to use GCC's -fms-extensions?

Tags: c, gcc

GCC has an option, `-fms-extensions`, which permits the use of anonymous struct members:

```
struct a {
    int x;
}

struct b {
    int y;
    struct a;
}
```

This allows access of an `x` element in `struct b` simply by using `b.x`. This is extremely useful, but it would seem that it is a Microsoft extension being emulated by GCC.

Will using this option make my code less portable, or is it considered "safe" to use?

Comment: IMHO,it's not so useful. Not so much to make the code gcc-dependent. So the answer is: yes.

Comment: This is a *horrifying* extension, please do **NOT** use it. In C++ the meaning is completely different and people will either misinterpret it or not know what it means if they haven't seen the C meaning before.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are looking for compatibility, it is never a good idea to set lax compiler options, stricter - the more portable

Answer (score 7):

Considering that a feature that seems equivalent, called anonymous structures and unions, was added to C in the 2011 edition of the standard (C11), I would say it's not such a bad idea to use this feature. MS compilers support it, GCC and "GNU C" compatible compilers support it if asked to, and new compilers conforming to the modern standard support it.

Comment: In that case though, the _nitpicky_ way of enabling this support in gcc would be to say `-std=c11` or `-std=iso9899:2011` (as per the gcc docs, http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html)- not by a specialcase compiler flag.

Comment: Well unfortunately, plenty of older gcc versions don't recognize `-std=c11` (because there *was no C11* when they were released), but still accept anonymous structures/unions as an extension. So if you want your software not to depend on very-recent gcc, you should make sure it's easy to compile with flags that make it work on older ones too.

Comment: Realize this is an old post but I believe the `-std=c11` would no longer accept the above code. The idea seems to be that only truly anonymous structs/unions are part of the standard.

Answer (score 4):

The flag -fms-extensions is used for "Accept some non-standard constructs used in Microsoft header files.". GCC is powerful because is created for different standards, so I don't think is a bad idea to use that in proper circumstances.

Comment: (Unless, of course, you're writing new code and might want to target a different compiler!)

Comment: It's a *horrible* idea to use it if you don't absolutely *need* to use it.  The option is there if you need it - nothing more.